# Add smile gif images in chat script

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am creating a chat script and I have added smile gif images, called them from there folder and I want users to add then to the textarea input on click.

[image]

[image]

But the problem is when any gif image is clicked, only the **html code** is posted in the textarea and I want an image to load instead. I have tried a lot of examples but all in vein.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function insertText(elemID, text) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(elemID);
    elem.innerHTML += text;
  }
</script>

<form action="" id="di_pr" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <?php
    $dirname = ".smileys/";
    $images = glob($dirname . "*.gif");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($images); $i++) {
        $image = $images[$i];
        ?>
      <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" onclick="insertText('aum', '<?php echo $image; ?>');" />

        <?php
    }
    ?>

  <div class="cdak brg">
        <textarea data-minlength="20" id="aum" name="rby_message">
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="uhn">
    <input type="button" value="Send" name="tlaj_submit" class="gpfy">
  </div>
</form>
```

The above code will output the **live example.**

Comment: You can only have text inside a text area, however, you could probably be able to set the image as a background-image on the textarea element.

Comment: For example, You could do `elem.style = "background-image: url('" + URL + "'); background-repeat: no-repeat";` where URL is the URL to the image.